# index of li in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJs & Bootstrap.

Trying to get the index of each li item so that, I can color each of them different.
How can I do that. Tried something like this.

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
   <li class="alert alert-{{bgcolor($index)}}" ng-repeat="item in todolist">     
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>    
   </li>                                                        
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.todolist = [
                { name: "Buy Food", done: false },
                { name: "Eat Food", done: false },
                { name: "Cook Food", done: true }
            ];
$scope.bgcolor = function (i) {
                var color = "";
                switch(i)
                {
                    case 1: color="success";
                    case 2: color = "warning";
                    case 3: color = "danger";
                }
                return color;

            };
```

Comment: JS lists have 0-based indexes. Have you tried `case 0: color="success" ...` ?

Comment: Never mind, that didn't fix it in Plunker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work, but you're missing `break;` in your switch:

```
switch(i) {
    case 1: color="success"; break;
    case 2: color = "warning"; break;
    case 3: color = "danger"; break;
}
```

`$index` is also 0 based, so the first item won't get a class from this.

Comment: I didn't even check for new answers until after I did this exact thing in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qgmOR51tusCBTWLaDs2l). +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
you can try something like this
<ul>
   <li class="alert alert-{{bgcolor($index)}}" ng-repeat="item in todolist">     
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>    
   </li>                                                        
</ul>

JS:

    $scope.todolist = [
                    { name: "Buy Food", done: false },
                    { name: "Eat Food", done: false },
                    { name: "Cook Food", done: true }
                ];
    $scope.bgcolor = function (i) {
                    var color = ['success','warning','danger'];

                    return color[index];

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $index with ng-repeat. (iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: It looks like OP was attempting to do that. Can you explain how?